# Micro frontend architecture in Angular

Tags: angular, design-patterns, architecture

I have 4 angular apps, let say A,B,C and D. Each apps are independent to each other and having their own node_modules.

I want to create an app which should have navigation for A,B,C and D, lets say this app as Shell app. Shell app should be independent of other apps, it should have its own node_modules. It should have header and footer and content section. In content section, micro apps should load. Once micro app gets loaded in content section, it's navigation should work as it is; it was working while running as individual app.

I am trying to achieve here micro-frontend architecture but I am not sure what should be my approach to achieve this in Angular.
Can anyone please guide or help.

Answer (score 0):

Micro services in not the correct term for frontend side.
Take a look at [micro frontend](https://dev.to/vicnovais/what-are-micro-frontends-4amf) architecture:

> Micro frontends follow the same principle as microservices on the backend. Each application lives independently and has a well defined objective.

Comment: corrected the question.